# Delphi application with weird behavior without Admin Rights

Tags: delphi, inno-setup, delphi-2010

I'm using D2010 and Windows 7 (64-bits) to develop an windows application. After compiling, I use InnoSetup to generate a installer. I open the intaller and it installs with no problem.

When I execute my application, it shows very odd behaviors, like hotkeys not working. However, if I run my Application with Admin Rights it runs flawlessly with no bug at all.

I also use an Access db, a .txt file, and r/w Registry Keys.

Is there a way to fix this without using admin rights?

Comment: Is there any problem of running with admin right?

Comment: None. I think its better the user not see the UAC screen if possible

Comment: Identify the part of your code that behaves unexpectedly. Use debugging techniques to determine the cause. The problem as posed here seems too vague. (You're not running Delphi and the debugger with admin rights, are you?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most plausible explanations are:

- You are trying to write to the program files directory.
- You are writing to the HKLM are of the registry.

Both of these are not possible for standard user. You should read the MSDN documentation for standard user app development. Start here:

[Windows Vista Application Development Requirements for User Account Control Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My Keys are under CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE. Is it part of HKLM keys too?

Comment: No, That's HKCU. Different branch from HKLM. HKLM is machine wide and needs admin rights to write.